# Testing fit of probability distribution

Tags: probability

If I have fitted training data to a probability distribution, e.g. a poisson distribution, how can I test this fit on some test data?

To fit the poisson distribution I am using R's `fitdistrplus` package that using MLE for determining the optimal coefficients of a given distribution. Therefore, I have the estimated $\lambda$ for a poisson distribution based on my training data but I am not sure how to test this on some unseen test data.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit#Fit_of_distributions

Comment: @Emre is there no way to compare errors or accuracies? Ideally, i want it to be very interpretable and easy to understand why one model is a better fit over another.

Comment: Maybe you want a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use chi-square test to check the goodness of fit to a specific distribution
http://courses.wcupa.edu/rbove/Berenson/10th%20ed%20CD-ROM%20topics/section12_5.pdf

Comment: I read over the notes and the chi-square test determines whether or not a poisson distribution is an appropriate fit to the data, but it does not help me compare several poisson distributions that are fit to the same data. Know any way I can compare these?

Comment: Hi guy, I think this post answers your question [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71720/error-metrics-for-cross-validating-poisson-models)